# Blazor internal webapi-requests gets timeout after deployment to hostingservice with IIS and .Net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor app which is running fine on my local dev-machine. Also deployment to azure is working fine. Only on the webserver of my hoster every webapi-request from my razor-page to the controller for example:

```
    wait Http.GetFromJsonAsync<PersData.Shared.UserInfo>("SecureNote");
```

gets a timeout-message and some strange log-entries:

fail: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
Microsoft.IdentityModel Version: 6.27.0.0. Date 03/30/2023 00:29:24. PII logging is OFF. See https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII for details.
Message: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'., InnerException: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException.
fail: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
Message: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://xxxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signinandregister/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
---> System.TimeoutException: A task was canceled.
---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

What setting is missing on that server? The hoster has done a newly installation of his webserver, something is now missing. Before that, the app was working fine.

Hope somebody can help.

startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<RazorPagesOptions>(options => options.RootDirectory = "/Pages");
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<SignOutSessionStateManager>();

            //if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
            //{
            //  services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
            //  {
            //      var urlHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
            //      return new HttpClient
            //      {
            //          BaseAddress = new Uri(urlHelper.BaseUri)
            //      };
            //  });
            //}


            services.AddMatBlazor();
            services.Configure<Models.MailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
            services.AddTransient<IMailService, MailService>();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));


            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddLocalization(); // options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resource");
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("de-CH"), new CultureInfo("en") };
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("de-CH");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            });

        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
            });

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            var localizeOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizeOptions.Value);
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
```

Thanks

I've updated all corresponding references and changed some logic about waiting of response. But with no luck. I don't think it is code-related, because the project is working as expected on azure webapp.

Comment: The problem cannot be solved based on these error messages alone, please check the console or Event Viewer for more detailed error messages.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.